# Specify class names for Proguard to avoid obfuscating to

Tags: android, proguard

I see with ProGuard you can specify a dictionary of names to be used when obfuscating (and these can be at the field/method, class or package level).

Is there a way to give it a list of names specifically not to obfuscate to? I tried putting a *!* in front in the dictionary but that didn't seem to work. As a bit of context, I'm thinking mainly not to obfuscate class names to r to avoid conflicts with the Android generated R class.

As an aside, it's worth checking out the example dictionaries in the ProGuard distribution (examples/dictionaries/) - the last two really made me chuckle!

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class com.company.package.SomeClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question while searching for the same thing.

This does not answer the core question,
but for your use-case adding this to `proguard-project.txt` should be enough:

```
-keep public class **.R {
  public *;
}

-keep public class **.R$* {
  public *;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work for my use case. I'm making an Android library with the code included in an obfuscated jar (rather than as Java source files) so I'm not actually including the R class in the jar in the first place. It's pretty horrible but the best I can think of for now at least is specifying a (long!) list of values in a dictionary avoiding 'r'. Brittle I know, but hey! Thanks anyway though.

Comment: I was having an issue with some other library using a particular class name (like Ab.class).
Also, in my project, I am keeping the R (and its subclasses) in order to build the project successfully. Then I decompile the .apk, delete R and R$* and use that as my obfuscated .jar. Might be helpful to you later, too...

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard already avoids conflicts between class names, preserved or not, from a dictionary or not, so you shouldn't need any special strategies. If you do end up with conflicting class names, you can report it as a bug.

Comment: Hi Eric. Sorry I never replied to this - must have missed the email notification! Just to say this isn't a bug in ProGuard - it's doing what it should do. It's just that when I'm obfuscating there is no other class at that point called 'R' (or 'r') and so it (validly) uses 'r' as a substitution. The R class is generated later by the user using the library and that's where the problem lies. ProGuard is awesome by the way!!

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Specifying a long custom dictionary, like you have done, might be the best solution. You could also try to use `-repackageclasses` to move classes with obfuscated names out of the way, but that's not ideal for a library.